# MariaDB empty user in user table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an issue with a couple of users in the database.

I noticed this when tried to add a new user, the CREATE USER, GRANT and FLUSH PRIVILEGES get executed correctly and **SHOW GRANTS FOR 'reporte'** shows the correct information for the new user, but i'm unable to use it for login to the database.

I went to look for the user in the mysql.user table, and it gets inserted BUT i also have these blank users (with no password)

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select Host, User, Password from mysql.user;
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host                  | User        | Password                                  |
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost             | root        |                                           |
| localhost.localdomain | root        |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1             | root        |                                           |
| ::1                   | root        |                                           |
| localhost             |             |                                           |
| localhost.localdomain |             |                                           |
| localhost             | freepbxuser | *1F0450426F77A1                           |
| %                     | reportes    | *2BA18D13                                 |
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to DROP them with **DROP USER ''** but of course it shows an error.

This is FreePBX system and regardless of the bug report on their part I want to know what happens if I just do

```
DELETE FROM mysqluser where User = '' and Host = 'localhost';
```

Is the same as DROP USER?
I haven't been able to find the answer in the documentation.
The version is 5.5.60-MariaDB

Comment: I think you have an answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/cannot-drop-anonymous-user-from-mysql-user

Comment: Thank you! Now I know why I didin't find the answer here :)